# Want to use Query builder in Kohana3 ORM

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I  want to use Query builder methods in Kohana 3 ORM so is it possbile to do that? And I want some of my function inside Kohana ORM based Model, for example if I do some thing in a function and it belongs to some model that is already an ORM based Model then I want to write that function in it and is it possible that I can use Query Builder or ORM inside those methods or class?
like

```
class Abc_Model extends ORM{
    function setAbc($a){
          DB::insert($table,$a);
    }

    function getSomething(){
         $x=$this->x->find_all();
         return $x;
    }


 }
```

So can I do such things in ORM and how and will it be a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query builder methods on ORM objects anywhere, thanks to __call().

So:

```
// inside the model
public function find_all_specific($val)
{
    return $this->where('specific','=',$val)->find_all();
}
```

There are quite a few good docs on using Ko3 ORM, you can start with userguide:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/using (switch to 3.0 if you're using 3.0.x)

Comment: so I can use my get something method like this in controller:
   
     `code` $info=$model->find_all_specific($val); `code`

Comment: exactly, and you can also say $info = $model->where... anywhere you want

Comment: Note that if you want to set table name (required for `from()` method) or DB object (for `execute()` method), you should use `$this->_table_name` and `$this->_db`